# How many named ranges can a single Google Spreadsheet have?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges

Is there even a limit to the number of *named ranges* that you can create within a single Google Spreadsheet?

It's rather cumbersome to add a new one, so I would prefer to not just open a spreadsheet and start making them over and over until it tells me there's a limit after 100 or 255 or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make 4963 named ranges, before the execution time of the Google Apps Script expired, using this piece of code.

### Code

```
function namedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i=1; i<5000; i++) {
    var r = ss.getRange('A'+i);
    ss.setNamedRange("test"+i, r);
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

If you plan on making larger named ranges (I created only one celled ranges), I guess it will take longer and thus reduce the amounts you can make.

If you're about to add them manually, I'd say you're safe.

Comment: Oh, well I imagine that nearly 5000ish is plenty even if you're naming almost every special value in your spreadsheet.